# Strange behaviour in drools data table when cell is null

Tags: drools

I have a data table (XLS) combined with a template (DRT) and need a short circuit for checking if the cell is null, e.g.

```
template header
bar

// ...

rule
when
  A(foo == @{bar})
then
  list.add(@{baz})
end
```

Will evaluate to `true` if `foo == null && bar == null` and thus the rule gets incorrectly picked.

All possible null checks won't work, e.g.

1. `A(this != null && foo != @{bar})`
2. `A(@{bar} != null && foo != @{bar})`

And now the curious part:

If I add a reference to `bar` in the when section, e.g. `list.add(@{bar})` it works perfectly fine and the rule won't get picked.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "rule ... gets picked"? I've read this three times and am still not sure whether you have a problem during rule generation or rule execution.

Comment: The `then` clause of the rule gets executed although the cell and the value is null. You can check the value by checking it but not the cell.